# How to plot multiple series with different time values one the same line chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I have a set of items with the following values: [username (string), score (number), date (datetime), comment (string)].

For example:

```
[['joe', 0.3, 5/5/16, "bla"],
['joe', 0.6, 6/5/16, "bli"],
['jim', 0.4, 6/5/16, "blo"],
['jim', 0.7, 7/5/16, "blu"]]
```

I want to plot one line for each username (I'll have more than 2) on the same line chart, with the date as the horizontal axis and the score on the vertical axis, with a different color for each line.

In the "multiple line types" example in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), both series have the same time ticks. Anybody can help / point me to some doc to plot multiple lines with different time values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in google charts, series' are determined by columns, e.g.

Label, Series 1, Series 2, Series 3

as such, recommend having each user in their own column

this will automatically create multiple lines with different colors

if a certain user doesn't have a value for a specific date, use `null`

then use following in config options, to prevent breaks in the line

`interpolateNulls: true`

resulting data table would look something like...

```
['Date', 'Jim', 'Joe'],
['5/5/16', null, 0.3],
['6/5/16', 0.4, 0.6],
['7/5/16', 0.7, null],
```

not sure what the comment is for, chart won't accept unless used as a tooltip or annotation...

Comment: If there is no option to let google charts know what columns to use for x and y axis and what column to use to identify a series (as I was expecting!) I'll do that, thanks.

Comment: no, each chart has a specific [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format) that must be adhered to...